# Getting deprecated error for guzzle http in php 8.1 backup and migrate azure module

Tags: 9, backups

I am using php 8.1 for drupal 9.5.9 application. I wanted to take and restore database and code backup for which I am using Backup and Migrate module with backup and migrate azure module. But I am getting following error due to which I am not able to upload files on azure blob storage:

Deprecated function: Return type of GuzzleHttp\Cookie\CookieJar::getIterator() should either be compatible with IteratorAggregate::getIterator(): Traversable, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in include() (line 10 of /app/code/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Cookie/CookieJar.php)

Haven't found any solution for this yet...

Comment: Use drush or mysql dump for DB backup. Backup Migrate often eat all PHP memory and crashed.